# Edit eastAsia attribute in OpenXML

Tags: c#, xml, openxml

I have an issue with our firm's Normal.dotm related to the eastAsia attribute in `styles.xml`.  If you're interested, you can find [a history of the issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15938942/wordml-eastasia-attribute-causing-error).  We can't just replace the template firmwide without overwriting custom styles/macros, etc.  I have almost no experience with OpenXML, but I thought it might hold a solution to the problem. However, all the articles and tutorials I've found haven't been much help.  They all reference the "Document" part and are focused on changing content rather than elements and attributes.

Basically, I need to loop through every `<w:rFonts>` element and change the `w:eastAsia` attribute from `"Times New Roman"` to `"MS Mincho."`  This is the only part I feel confident about:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Packaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace eastAsiaFix
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument myDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\Desktop\eastAsiaFix.dotm", true))
        {
            StyleDefinitionsPart styles = myDocument.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart;

            if (styles == null)
            {
                return;
            }
        }

    }
  }
}
```

I think what I need is something like the following:

```
foreach (OpenXMLElement theStyle in styles.Styles.ChildElements)
{
     if (theStyle.LocalName = "style")
     {
         theStyle.StyleRunProperties.RunFonts.EastAsia.Value = "MS Mincho"; //faking this
     }
}
```

How do I get to the `w:rFonts` node and edit the `eastAsia` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two different solutions to change the *East Asian font* value.
The first solution just changes the *East Asian font* value for all `RunFonts`
under the `Styles` collection. This solutions would also change the *East Asian
font* value for the document default paragraph and run properties (`DocDefaults` class, w:docDefaults).

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\Desktop\eastAsiaFix.dotm", true))
{
  StyleDefinitionsPart stylesPart = myDocument.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart;

  if (stylesPart == null)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("No styles part found.");
    return;
  }

  foreach(var rf in stylesPart.Styles.Descendants<RunFonts>())
  {          
    if(rf.EastAsia != null)
    {
      Console.Out.WriteLine("Found: {0}", rf.EastAsia.Value);
      rf.EastAsia.Value = "MS Mincho";
    }        
  }      
}
```

The second solution would be to change the *East Asian font* value
only for the style definitions (and not for the document default paragraph and run properties):

```
using (WordprocessingDocument myDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(@"C:\users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\Desktop\eastAsiaFix.dotm", true))
{
  StyleDefinitionsPart stylesPart = myDocument.MainDocumentPart.StyleDefinitionsPart;

  if (stylesPart == null)
  {
    Console.Out.WriteLine("No styles part found.");
    return;
  }

  foreach(var style in stylesPart.Styles.Descendants<Style>())
  {          
    foreach(var rf in style.Descendants<RunFonts>())
    {
      if(rf.EastAsia != null)
      {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Found: {0}", rf.EastAsia.Value);
        rf.EastAsia.Value = "MS Mincho";
      } 
    }               
  }      
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Hans! I used the second solution to avoid changing the defaults, which aren't a problem.  It worked great!  

If you don't mind my asking, why do you use "var Style" and "var rf" instead of "Style style" and "RunFonts rf?"  This is one of the things that I got hung up on when I was experimenting with different `foreach` statements.

Comment: @tmoore82: Oh, it's just my personal preference. You could also explicitly type the variables.